# Is there a better way to named pipe a `cv::mat` variable

Tags: c++, opencv, named-pipes, mat

I'm trying to pipe a `cv::mat` variable from one C program to an other they are independent of each other.

I already create a basic code sourced from forums and search, I have 2 programs, `writer.c` and `reader.c`.

The `writer.c` have a `cv::mat img` variable in it and I need pipe it to `reader.c` `cv::mat img` to be showed up with `imshow()`;

I'm merging code from multiple sources hoping this work, because I can find a working sample

My sources:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/2789967/11632453
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/30274548/11632453
>
> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/222075/pipe-named-fifo
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/36080965/11632453

This is my evolution until now:

Code from file `writer.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat img;
    img = imread("/home/filipe/Documentos/QT_Projects/FIFO_Writer/download.jpeg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file

    if(! img.data )                              // Check for invalid input
    {
        cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", img );
    //waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    //return 0;




    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";

    // create the FIFO (named pipe)
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

    // write "Hi" to the FIFO
    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    //write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi"));
    write(fd, img.data, sizeof(img.data));
    close(fd);

    // remove the FIFO
    unlink(myfifo);

    return 0;
}
```

Code from `reader.c`

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

#define MAX_BUF 1024

int main()
{
    int fd;
    char * myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo";
    char buf[MAX_BUF];

    /* open, read, and display the message from the FIFO */
    fd = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buf, MAX_BUF);
    printf("Received: %s\n", buf);
    close(fd);

    Mat img(177, 284, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 0));

    img.data= ((unsigned char*) (buf));
    namedWindow( "Display window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
    imshow( "Display window", img );

    waitKey(0); // Wait for a keystroke in the window
    return 0;
}
```

I got no errors from this code, but, I got no Image ether
no window apear to be created to show the image.

Any help?
Anything to help me passing through?
Any direction?

thanks

Solved in https://answers.opencv.org/question/216274/is-there-a-better-way-to-named-pipe-a-cvmat-variable/

Comment: printf("Received: %s\n", buf); is undefined behavior IMHO, unless you are sure that buf is zero terminated. Secondly, do you see something inside the buffer, if yes then the problem is how you create the image otherwise the problem is in the transmission. Lasty (and probably not related to your problem), wouldn't the assignment img.data= ((unsigned char*) (buf)); create a leak? I am no expert of OpenCV but I would expect data to already point to a buffer before assignment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, sorry but I'm no following you in all your explanation, you are talking too technical, I'm a dum noobee on C, opencv, and all linux programming... any way... I understand you say the problem is not on pipe but yes on how disintegrate the image  and reassemble it so I create a copy of this post on https://answers.opencv.org/question/216274/is-there-a-better-way-to-named-pipe-a-cvmat-variable/

Comment: What I said is that you should try to do find out if the problem is the pipe or the image creation. A way to do it is to print the content of the buffer upon transmission and receipt. I would avoid using %s because the buffer might not have a 0 as last element. You can do a loop on the first, say, 100 elements and print them one after the other both on send and receive.

Comment: You're right, I have a problem with the pipe, I add `printf("%u\n",img.data);` on both programs and run them, I got different outputs

Comment: Solved in https://answers.opencv.org/question/216274/is-there-a-better-way-to-named-pipe-a-cvmat-variable/
The problem it's the buffer size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved [Here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/216274/is-there-a-better-way-to-named-pipe-a-cvmat-variable/)

Just change the buffer sizer according with the image size